# C menu - Else if

Tags: c

I am new to C and I need to build a menu with loops for a project.
I had 2 problems.

1) I want to add a char to the else if for asking a something after press "2" at the main menu, the question will be "Are you going to the event?" the user can enter the chat "Y" or "N"  after that the program will thank the user and break, other input will send the user to the main menu

2) I want to count the number of loops that been made with the program when i press "3" at the main menu, i don't have any idea how i combine count option with "else if"

```
int choice;
while (1)

{
    printf("Main Menu\n");
    printf("\n");

    printf("Please enter num:");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    printf("You entered %d\n", choice);
    if (choice == 4)
    {
        break;
    }

    else if (choice == 1)
        printf("Returned to main menu\n");

    else if (choice == 2)
        printf("Are you going to the event?\n");

    else if (choice == 3)
        printf("number of loops that made are \n");

    else if (choice == 4)
        printf("Bye!\n");

    else
        printf("Wrong Input!\n");
}

printf("Bye!\n");

return 0;
```

}

Comment: for 1 - i think that i need to add for loop but the phrase is on else if loop already.

Answer (score 0):

for your counting loops problem simply creat an int variable and at the end of every loop add 1 to it.
e.g

```
int count=0;
while(...)
{
    *code*
    count++;
}
```

for the other problem you can use

```
else if(choice==2)
{
    char going;
    printf("Are you going to the event? Y/N");
    scanf("%c",&going);
    if(going=='N'||going=='n')
        *code*
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    else if(going=='Y'||going=='y')
    {
        *code*
    }
}
```